# mingw64 pjsip sizeof(fd_set) always double sizeof(pj_fd_set_t) causing assertion in sock_select.c

Tags: c, windows, mingw, pjsip, msys2

I've compiled pjsip into my program that I'm writing in an msys2/mingw environment (64-bit). It compiles fine. However, when I run it in my program I'm getting an assertion

```
// Line 49 of ../src/pj/sock_select.c
sizeof(pj_fd_set_t)-sizeof(pj_sock_t)>=sizeof(fd_set)
```

Every time I run the program.

When I do some digging people talk about increasing PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES. So I did, and I put a printf in the function before the asserts to see what the sizes are:

```
// My PJ_FD_ZERO variant
PJ_DEF(void) PJ_FD_ZERO(pj_fd_set_t *fdsetp)
{
    printf( "PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES: %d, pj_fd_set_t: %I64d, pj_sock_t: %I64d, fd_set: %I64d\n", PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES, sizeof(pj_fd_set_t), sizeof(pj_sock_t), sizeof(fd_set) );
    PJ_CHECK_STACK();
    pj_assert(sizeof(pj_fd_set_t)-sizeof(pj_sock_t) >= sizeof(fd_set));

    FD_ZERO(PART_FDSET(fdsetp));
    PART_COUNT(fdsetp) = 0;
}
```

The program will output something like this:

```
10:27:43.477        os_core_win32.c !pjlib 2.9 for win32 initialized
10:27:43.507         sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES: 16384, pj_fd_set_t: 65552, pj_sock_t: 4, fd_set: 131080
```

However, when I tweak PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES the size of pj_fd_set_t increases *as it should* but! the sizeof(fd_set) also becomes slight less than DOUBLE whatever sizeof(pj_fd_set_t) is! The winsock guide says that I cannot set the size of fd_set so I am very confused how the size is getting set! I don't see anywhere in the pjsip code that this is being set.

So adjusting PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES is quite the losing battle.

How can I fix this so my code will stop asserting?

**Some references**

Bash script that I ran to configure pjsip

```sh
#!/bin/bash

JOPT=1
DEBUG=false
BUILD_ALL=true
CLEAN_BEFORE_BUILD=false

TOUCH_COMMAND="touch configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in"

while getopts ":pdj:o:c" opt; do
        case $opt in
                j)
                        JOPT="$OPTARG"
                        ;;
                c)
                        echo "Clean before build is set."
                        CLEAN_BEFORE_BUILD=true;
                        ;;
                d)
                        DEBUG=true
                        ;;
                o)
                        IFS=', ' read -r -a BUILD_OPTS <<< "${OPTARG}"
                        BUILD_ALL=false

                        for option in "${BUILD_OPTS[@]}" ; do
                                # Set individual
                                case $option in
                                        pjsip)
                                                BUILD_PJSIP=true;
                                                ;;
                                        *)
                                                echo "Unknown build option ${option}"
                                                exit
                                esac
                        done
                        ;;
                \?)
                        echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                :)
                        echo "Option -${OPTARG} requires an argument." >&2
                        exit 1
                        ;;
        esac
done

# Make the out
mkdir out
OUT_PREFIX="$( pwd )/out"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${OUT_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"

if [ "$DEBUG" = true ] ; then
MAKEFLAGS="-g -O0"
else
MAKEFLAGS="-O2"
fi

# Main directory
LIB_DIRECTORY="$(pwd)/lib"

# Descend
cd "${LIB_DIRECTORY}"

pwd

# pjsip
cd "${LIB_DIRECTORY}/pjsip"
if [ "${BUILD_ALL}" = true ] || [ "${BUILD_PJSIP}" = true ] ; then
        eval $TOUCH_COMMAND

        ./configure CFLAGS="${MAKEFLAGS} -I${OUT_PREFIX}/include" CXXFLAGS="${MAKEFLAGS}" LDFLAGS="-L${OUT_PREFIX}/lib" \
                --prefix="${OUT_PREFIX}" \
                --disable-openh264 \
                --disable-v4l2 \
                --disable-ffmpeg \
                --enable-libsamplerate \
                --disable-video \
                --enable-shared \
                --disable-static \
                --disable-libyuv \
                --with-external-speex \
                --with-gnutls \
                || exit

        if [ "${CLEAN_BEFORE_BUILD}" = true ] ; then
                make clean
        fi

        # Without this it breaks on msys2
        make -j $JOPT dep || exit
        # Make the actual
        make -j $JOPT || exit
        # Note, had issue with writing to //c/.../pkgconfig/libproject.pc
        make install || exit
fi
```

The assert screenshot

[image: assert screenshot]

--**Edit**--

Funny enough when I run this program the sizeof( fd_set ) is 520.

```
#include <winsock.h>

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::cout <<
        "sizeof( fd_set )=" << sizeof( fd_set ) << "\n"
        "FD_SETSIZE=" << FD_SETSIZE << std::endl;

    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Result:

```
sizeof( fd_set )=520
FD_SETSIZE=64
```

Comment: Looks like that code is assuming things about the layout of a `fd_set` that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Shawn which is quite amazing since it seems to have a relationship to pj_fd_set_t's size. sizeof( fd_set ) is never an arbitrary value even if I clean and re-build.

Comment: `fd_set` is an opaque type that you use the `FD_FOO` macros and `select()` to manipulate. From that snippet, it looks like that code assumes it's implemented in one particular way instead of treating it like a black box. Presumably it's compatible with whatever environment this library was developed on but not on yours.

Comment: @Shawn so how to fix? I'm dead in the water otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm that guy again answering my own question.

I think what was going on is that pjsip wasn't detecting that I was using windows with mingw despite it being detected on configure.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking target system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

I found this little nugget in the types.h

```
/** Socket handle. */
#if defined(PJ_WIN64) && PJ_WIN64!=0
    typedef pj_int64_t pj_sock_t;
#else
    typedef long pj_sock_t;
#endif
```

I think realized that pj_fd_set_t (which is comprised of pj_sock_t) would be smaller always than fd_set (which is comprised of fd) if the sizes are off. That would explain the proportional phenomenon. This is also because PJSIP defines FD_SETSIZE on Windows when detected.

So I just ran ./configure as I did above and then manually modified:

- build.mak
- build/os-auto.mak

Replacing PJ_AUTOCONF=1 with PJ_WIN32=1.

Then I manually modified the Makefile explicitly including the correct file.

```
include build/os-win32.mak
```

And then I compiled using make dep && make && make install

Finally, when I compiled it into my program it complained about implementing unicode string functions, so I looked at the file threw the error (pj/compat/string.h). I found the line #if defined(_MSC_VER) and added some more definitions as below to support MINGW macros.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
#   define strcasecmp   _stricmp
#   define strncasecmp  _strnicmp
#   define snprintf     _snprintf
#   define vsnprintf    _vsnprintf
#   define snwprintf    _snwprintf
#   define wcsicmp      _wcsicmp
#   define wcsnicmp     _wcsnicmp
#else
#   define stricmp      strcasecmp
#   define strnicmp     strncasecmp

#   if defined(PJ_NATIVE_STRING_IS_UNICODE) && PJ_NATIVE_STRING_IS_UNICODE!=0
#       error "Implement Unicode string functions"
#   endif
#endif
```

Then it worked!